# trying to get property non-object

Tags: php

When I run my php, I always get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\a\index_admin.php on line 42

I just want to show the admin's last name. here's my code.

```php
<?php
session_start();
$AdminID = $_SESSION['id'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file("admin.xml");

$admin = $xml->xpath("//*[admin_username=$AdminID]");
if(count($admin)>=1)
{
  $xml_string = '';
  while(list( , $Node) = each($admin))
  {
    $xml_string .= $Node->asXML();
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Admin Main menu</title>
  <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    function logout(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Your successfully logout from system.Thank for using this system!!");
      });
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <h1><u>Welcome Admin <?php echo $admin->admin_lname;?>.</u></h1>
  <h3>Admin menu</h3>
  <br/>
  <br><a class = "MenuButton" href = "insert menu.php" target = "Content"><b>Insert Data</b></a>
  <br><a class = "MenuButton" href = "admin profile.php" target = "Content"><b>View Profile</b></a>
  <br><a class = "MenuButton" href = "admin search.php" target = "Content"><b>Search Shoe</b></a>
  <br><a class = "MenuButton" href = "logout.php" onclick = "logout()"><b>Logout</b></a>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Line 42 would be this : `<h1><u>Welcome Admin <?php echo $admin->admin_lname;?>.</u></h1>`

I also tried `<h1><u>Welcome Admin <?php echo $admin[0]->admin_lname;?>.</u></h1>`
and it returned this:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\a\index_admin.php on line 42

admin.xml:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="admin.xsl"?>
 <ALDO>
   <admin>
     <admin_username>admin</admin_username>
     <admin_password>1234</admin_password>
     <admin_fname>Abu</admin_fname>
     <admin_lname>Ali</admin_lname>
     <admin_address>Pandan Jaya</admin_address>
     <admin_salary>1900</admin_salary>
     <admin_telno>03-92844476</admin_telno>
   </admin>
 </ALDO>
```

Comment: seems like your xpath query is probably coming up empty.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="admin.xsl"?>
<ALDO>
  <admin>
    <admin_username>admin</admin_username>
    <admin_password>1234</admin_password>
    <admin_fname>Abu</admin_fname>
    <admin_lname>Ali</admin_lname>
    <admin_address>Pandan Jaya</admin_address>
    <admin_salary>1900</admin_salary>
    <admin_telno>03-92844476</admin_telno>
  </admin>
</ALDO>

Comment: and `$_SESSION['id']` contains the string `admin`, correct?

Comment: Your xpath query is wrong. Should be `$xml->xpath( "*/admin_username[text() = '$AdminID']"` (careful with injection here).

Comment: `"//*[admin_username=$AdminID]"` means find an element at least 2 tags deep with a property of "admin_username" equal to "admin" (which isn't even a string).

Comment: @soulseekah I noticed that just now as well. Want to write it up as an answer or should I?

Comment: @Tim, feel free to write it up as an answer, but only if OP acknowledges that a wrong query was in fact the issue. Include some links to XPath basics and cheatsheets as well ;)

Comment: @soulseekah That gloss of the query doesn't seem quite right to me. AFAIK, `//` means "a descendant element at any level", not "an element at least 2 tags deep", and `*[admin_username=something]` (ignoring the quoting issue) means an element with a *child element* called `admin_username`, which in turn has *text content* matching the `something`. ("Property" doesn't mean anything in an XML context, but matching an *attribute* would be `*[@admin_username=something]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath query, as I suspected, was coming back with no results. I modified it slightly and was successful.

Change this line:

```
 $admin = $xml->xpath("//*[admin_username=$AdminID]");
```

To this:

```
 $admin = $xml->xpath("//*[admin_username='$AdminID']");
```

All you needed was quotes around the username string.

I personally had no luck with the query from soulseekah in the comments.

I also want to mention: you shouldn't be storing passwords in cleartext. Use a hashing function.